# How do you do $elemMatch in Mongokit?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongokit

I have documents like:

```
{
name: 'Nicholas',
friends : ['Amy', 'Joe', 'Amanda']
},
{
name: 'John',
friends : ['Amy', 'Amanda', 'Sam', 'Steve']
},
```

and I'd like to find all documents where 'Joe' is in the friends array.

In Mongo I guess this would be:

```
db.people.find({ 'friends' : { $elemMatch : 'Joe' } }
```

but how do I do this in Python with MongoKit:

```
connection.People.find( ?? )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following answer is based on my test in mongo shell -

I just created a sample in my collection. Here is how you can search for the documents with "Joe" -

```
db.sample3.find({"friends":"Joe"})
```

output is `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5339c9ff0bb9bc1b3a5bf7a4"), "name" : "Nicholas", "friends" : [ "Amy", "Joe", "Amanda" ] }`

For the query `db.sample3.find({"friends":"Amy"})`, output is -

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5339c9ff0bb9bc1b3a5bf7a4"), "name" : "Nicholas", "friends" : [ "Amy", "Joe", "Amanda" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5339ca120bb9bc1b3a5bf7a5"), "name" : "John", "friends" : [ "Amy", "Amanda", "Sam", "Steve" ] }
```

The query {"friends":"Joe"} works. So, you should be able to use the same in Mongokit.
Here is the document I created -

```
db.sample3.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5339c9ff0bb9bc1b3a5bf7a4"),
    "name" : "Nicholas",
    "friends" : [
        "Amy",
        "Joe",
        "Amanda"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5339ca120bb9bc1b3a5bf7a5"),
    "name" : "John",
    "friends" : [
        "Amy",
        "Amanda",
        "Sam",
        "Steve"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is not MongoKit.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The point I am demonstrating is you don't need $elemMatch. A simple {"friends":"Joe"} would do.